# python doctest exception test handling

Tags: python, doctest

I have the following contents in a file called `test2.txt`.

```
>>> def faulty():  
... yield 5  
... return 7  
Traceback(most recent call last):  
SyntaxError: 'return' with argument inside generator(<doctest test.txt[0]>,line 3)
```

I invoke the test run with `python -m test2.txt`. The results below are quite out of my expectation.

[image: screenshot of terminal output]

My thought was that the test should be successful because I have written the expected output in my `test2.txt` file and it 'almost' matches what I got from the console output. I tried adding the `'File "G:\"'.... line`? but the test still failed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

doctest is extremely careful with the format of expected exceptions. You missed a space:

`Traceback(most recent call last):` should be `Traceback (most recent call last):`

Moreover, this would still fail, as your traceback message is overly specific (and also has incorrect whitespace)! Use the `ELLIPSIS` or `IGNORE_EXCEPTION_DETAIL` flags to doctest to make doctest less picky about matching exceptions, as so:

```
>>> def faulty(): # doctest: +IGNORE_EXCEPTION_DETAIL  
...     yield 5  
...     return 7  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
SyntaxError: 'return' with argument inside generator (...)
```

(`ELLIPSIS` would work here too)

Comment: thank you very much. I follow your advice to modify the initial text file __extremely__ carefully and now it works though i have not yet tried the **flags** you talk about. I might take a try as my learning moves on.

Comment: It worth to note that this flag also cause exception message to be ignored.